# Writing a multidimensional array to a text file as plain text with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array like this:

```
[["Hello", "World"],
 ["How", "are", "you?"],
 ["Bye" "World"]]
```

And I would like it to be put into a text file like this:

```
Hello World
How are you?
Bye World
```

I have no idea how to do this, please can someone help.

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file to a file or are you looking for join() the elements of the inner lists into strings?

Comment: What research have you done, and what have you tried already?  Please *specifically* let us know where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
text = [["Hello", "World"],
 ["How", "are", "you?"],
 ["Bye", "World"]]

with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for outer in text:
        for i, inner in enumerate(outer):
            if i == (len(outer) - 1):
                f.write(f'{inner}')
            else:
                f.write(f'{inner} ')
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: No need for `f.close()` when using the file as a context manager (i.e. in a `with` block). Also, this leaves a trailing space on each line (might not be a problem, depends on the exact use case).

Comment: Cool, although now note that you'll miss a space sometimes. For example with `text = [["Hello", "Hello"], ["Hello", "World"]]`

Comment: @slothrop hahaha, that's true. Didn't even think about it. I just made a new edit

Comment: Why not simply use `f.write(' '.join(outer))`?

Comment: Continuing from what @S3DEV said, this answer is very much overcomplicated. I've posted a much briefer version.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative that's much shorter and more efficient.

```py
text = [["Hello", "World"],
 ["How", "are", "you?"],
 ["Bye", "World"]]

with open('test.txt','w+') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(map(' '.join,text)))
```

Comment: Nice.  Perhaps, improve the answer for the (presumably) novice Python user by explaining how and why the code can be compacted as such.  Specifically, why the `map` function is used and how `join` works.  Of course, including links to the documentation.